# View config not found for name div

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Card component from shards-react isn't working

When I run `react-native run-android` I get an Error:

> View config not found for name div.Help please thanks.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Card } from "shards-react";

class User extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { name, avatar, email} = this.props;

    const userDetails = (
        <View>
          <Image style={styles.img} source={require('../assets/logo.jpg')} />
          <Text>Name: {name} </Text>
          <Text>Email: {email} </Text>
        </View>
    );
    return (
      <Card>
      {userDetails}
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  img:{
    marginTop:250,
    height:120,
    width: 120,
    borderRadius: 70,
  }
});
User.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  avatar: PropTypes.string,
  email: PropTypes.string,
  isLoading: PropTypes.bool
};

export default User;
```

Is this library work only for web ? Not for mobile apps ?
If yes is there another one ?

[image: ERROR]

Comment: I think it's only for `reactjs`

Comment: [Shards React](https://designrevision.com/downloads/shards-react/) is only for ReactJS

Answer (score 2):

`shards-react` by default uses `<div>` tag for building Cards. `<div>` is an invalid React Native Component. But `shards-react` allows passing other components to use instead of `<div>`. Try to pass `tag` prop to `Card` like this:

```
return (
    <Card tag={View}>
        {userDetails}
    </Card>
);
```

If this won't help you, then this library cannot be used in `react-native`.